# include gwt-graphics into a Eclipse WebApp-Project

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I try to include the gwt-graphics library into a WebApp-Project made with Eclipse.

This is the description: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-graphics/wikis/Manual.wiki

"Download gwt-graphics.jar and add it to the class path of your GWT project. In addition, you have to add the following line to the GWT module file:  After these two steps, you are ready to use GWT Graphics in your GWT project!"

I have done this and after I start the app in super-dev-mode, I got an error from the compiler:

"[ERROR] Unable to find 'org/vaadin/gwtgraphics/GWTGraphics.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?"

I am not sure how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it to the class path? If not, you can right click to the jar file and do Add to Classpath

Comment: I put it to the build path. There is no "add to classpath".